# how to install Watcom C/C++ 11.0 and i686-pc-msdosdjgpp on ubuntu

Tags: watcom

I need to install these two requirements on Ubuntu 22.04: Watcom C/C++ 11.0 for DOS32 OVL wrapper i686-pc-msdosdjgpp cross toolchain (binutils, gcc, dxe3gen) for DJGPP DXE wrappers I can't find a valid guide on google. Thank you so much.

I can't figure out how to do it